# MahApps - Como criar botão de Usuário com Menu na Barra de Títulos da aplicação

Tags: wpf

Tenho um botão **usuário** na minha barra de títulos que permitirá que o mesmo alterne entre usuários ou saia da aplicação. Como eu faço para criar um **menu** que contenha essas duas funcionalidades?

```
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <controls:WindowCommands>           
            <Button>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Ellipse Width="30"
                       Height="30"
                       Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">                        
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Jalber" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </controls:WindowCommands>
    </controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Há um exemplo parecido na própria documentação do MahApps.

### XAML

Coloque o seguinte código dentro da tag `Controls:MetroWindow` no arquivo de layout da sua `Window`:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Content="usuário" Click="Username_Click" >
            <Button.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Trocar usuário" Click="ChangeUser_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Sair"  Click="Exit_Click" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Button.ContextMenu>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Seu layout deverá ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Code behind

No arquivo `.cs` da sua `Window`, adicione o seguinte código:

```
private void Username_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = button.ContextMenu;
    contextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void ChangeUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

O método `Username_Click` irá mostrar o menu criado anteriormente no XAML e os outros dois métodos serão chamados ao clicar no item do menu "Trocar usuário" e "Sair", respectivamente. Basta adicionar o código desejado dentro de cada método.

### Resultado final

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]